# How to create PivotTable using Apache POI using LARGE data set

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Java and Apache POI to create Excel reports. I have a large amount of data (300,000+ rows, 7 columns) already written to a SXSSFWorkbook. Furthermore, I now need to create a PivotTable based off this data written to the workbook. I understand that you need a XSSFSheet as your data source when constructing a XSSFPivotTable. However, this is just not possible given the 300,000+ rows of data in my sheet (hence, why I used a streaming model opposed to xssf).

So far, I have tried creating a XSSFWorkbook after writing to my SXSSFWorbook. From there, I tried pulling the data sheet as a XSSFSheet. Unfortunately, this does not work due to the previously mentioned memory constraints of XSSFSheet.

Is there any neat programming trick to do this using Apache POI? If not, is there some other library that will allow me to create PivotTables from large data sets in Java?

Thank you.

Comment: why is that no possible? You already created the sheet, no?

Comment: The sheet that was created when I first wrote my data to the SXSSFWorkbook was a SXSSFSheet. To create a PivotTable using Apache POI, I require a XSSFSheet as the data source. However, if I were to convert my SXSSFSheet to a XSSFSheet, the memory constraints of the XSSFSheet are broken due to my many lines of data.

Comment: I think this answer maybe your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49819519/9637306 Bye