# Apache POI - is there a way to create a pivot table where the source table is a SXSSFSheet?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot

This is the case:
I have to use SXSSFWorkbook (Streaming version of XSSFWorkbook) to create my Excel, because I have to create a sheet with 700000/800000 rows with about 20 columns. **This sheet represents the source table for my final Pivot.**

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbook();
XSSFSheet pivotSheet = workbook.getXSSFWorkbook().createSheet("Pivot sheet");
AreaReference ar = ....:
CellReference cr = ....;
XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivotSheet.createPivotTable(ar, cr); // ERROR!!
```

The problem is that, when I try to create this Pivot on that source, the **XSSFPivotTable.createPivotTable** method not work, despite AreaReference and CellReference arguments are ok.

If I use XSSFWorkbook (not streaming version) with less rows, all is ok, but I do not reach my goal!

Can someone give me a solution? **Thank you very much!!!!!**

Stefano

Comment: I underline that my problem is on the SOURCE table SXSSFsheet (streaming) of my Pivot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SXSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html) can be created from `XSSFWorkbook`.

So what I would do is creating `XSSFWorkbook` having a `XSSFSheet` with at least the headings of the data and another `XSSFSheet` for the pivot table. Then creating  the `XSSFPivotTable` on this `XSSFSheet` but making the reference to the data sheet big enough for later data.

Then I would creating the `SXSSFWorkbook` from this `XSSFWorkbook`, getting the data sheet as `SXSSFSheet` and then streaming the big amount of data into the data sheet.

Complete example:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.SpreadsheetVersion;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.*;

import java.util.Random;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class SXSSFPivotTableTest {

 private static void streamCellData(Sheet sheet, int rowsCount) {

  for (int r = 1; r <= rowsCount; r++) {
   Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
   Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("Name " + ((r-1) % 4 + 1));
   cell = row.createCell(1);
   cell.setCellValue(r * new java.util.Random().nextDouble());
   cell = row.createCell(2);
   cell.setCellValue(r * new java.util.Random().nextDouble());
   cell = row.createCell(3);
   cell.setCellValue("City " + ((r-1) % 3 + 1));  
  }

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

  int rowsCount = 1000000;

  //first create XSSFWorkbook
  XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

  //create XSSFSheet with at least the headings
  XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");
  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
  Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue("Name");
  cell = row.createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue("Value1");
  cell = row.createCell(2);
  cell.setCellValue("Value2");
  cell = row.createCell(3);
  cell.setCellValue("City");

  //create XSSFSheet for pivot table
  XSSFSheet pivotSheet = wb.createSheet("Pivot sheet");

  //create pivot table
  XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivotSheet.createPivotTable(
    new AreaReference(new CellReference("Sheet1!A1"), 
                      new CellReference("Sheet1!D" + (rowsCount +1)), //make the reference big enough for later data
                      SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007),
    new CellReference("A5"));
  //Configure the pivot table
  //Use first column as row label
  pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
  //Sum up the second column
  pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 1);
  //Avarage the third column
  pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.AVERAGE, 2);
  //Add filter on forth column
  pivotTable.addReportFilter(3);

  //now create SXSSFWorkbook from XSSFWorkbook
  SXSSFWorkbook swb = new SXSSFWorkbook(wb);
  SXSSFSheet ssheet = swb.getSheet("Sheet1");

  //now stream the big amount of data to build the pivot table on into Sheet1
  streamCellData(ssheet, rowsCount);

  swb.write(new FileOutputStream("SXSSFPivotTableTest.xlsx"));
  swb.close();
  swb.dispose();

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Axel, great solution, which also helped me out!