# Create pivot table from huge xslx files using java

Tags: java, apache-poi, pivot-table, large-files

I have an issue while trying to create 2 pivot tables from one large (~100MB) xslx file using java POI. I have to process two sheets. I got a OOM error after nearly 10 minutes, when processing the last line of the following code:

```
File lFile = new File("workbook.xlsx");

        try {
            System.out.println("Debug 1");
            XSSFWorkbook myWb = new XSSFWorkbook(lFile);
...
```

I'm not sure that SXSSF and other formats could help me as I don't really know how I could work around this issue. I could split the file in smaller ones, but the issue is the same if I want to split it: I still have to load the file in POI, and I still want 1 pivot table per sheet (the large one).

Is it possible to read the large file using something else, to copy the read data into split files, and to create the pivot table in a new file using multiple files?

The fact is that my final xslx file needs to have access to the data from the two sheets as the pivot tables are used to easily access those data with filters (as well as being used to check counts on some filters).

Every idea is welcome!

Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49803148/apache-poi-is-there-a-way-to-create-a-pivot-table-where-the-source-table-is-a/49819519#49819519 for how to stream data via `SXSSF` into a pivot table.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you, I will try it.