# How to create pivot table in SXSSF sheet using apache poi library in java?

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getXSSFWorkbook().getSheetAt(0);
XSSFSheet pivot_sheet = workbook.getXSSFWorkbook().createSheet("Sheet1");    
XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivot_sheet.createPivotTable(new AreaReference("B10:AJ24"), new CellReference("B2"),sheet);
```

I am getting following error at above line -

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPivotCacheDefinition.createCacheFields(XSSFPivotCacheDefinition.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.createPivotTable(XSSFSheet.java:4065)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49803148/apache-poi-is-there-a-way-to-create-a-pivot-table-where-the-source-table-is-a/49819519#49819519

Comment: Above link has example that requires to create sheet(which holds data) priorly, while my use case is not such.

Comment: My linked example is a complete working example for how to fill the data range of a pivot table using `SXSSF`. There is not another possibility to do so as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find solution for this using apache poi. 
Workaround that I used is mentioned as follows :

- Create SXSSFWorkbook as below
  SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("xyz.xlsm")));
  workbook.removeSheetAt(0);
- xyz.xlsm is macro enabled excel which holds VBA code for generating pivot
- Write in workbook as usual
- Pivots will get generated in excel on opening it after download